# Timestamping print from ArcReader?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcreader, arcgis-publisher

I'm setting up an published arcreader file, and was searching for a way to add a date/time stamp to the printed map.

Is there a way to add a dynamic text box to a published pmf file that will show the date that the map was opened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only by using an OLE Object (MS Word with Date and Time) when published the object becomes static.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Map_Contents_Summary/000s00000011000000/

Answer (score 2):

"The Publisher Map Title is a single text element" so try putting some dynamic text formatting into it like:

```
Date: <dyn type="date" format="dd MMM yy"/>
Time: <dyn type="time" format="HH.mm.ss"/>
```

Do this before you publish the map and it should carry through to the PMF.

Answer (score 1):

While kind of kludgy, I have been able to get dynamic text into a published map (.pmf file) using ArcGIS 9.3.1 and MS Access.  Note that while it works for published maps, it won't work for packaged/exported maps & datasets.  As a read-only viewer on a company network, it works well.

Briefly, I create a point shapefile with one data point falling somehwere in my final layout viewframe.  I symbolize the point to be transparant and/or not visible.  I create a single attribute field with a unique ID.

In MS Access I create a new db with a single table and a single view/query.  The table has a single field with the same value as the unique ID for the shapefile - to be able to join.  The query is built to include the unique ID as well as a current date calculation.  The SQL text looks like this... "SELECT DateLink.ID, Now() AS CurDate FROM DateLink".

Back in ArcGIS the shapefile is joined to the query, adding a CurDate field to the shape.  Lable the point with the CurDate value.  As this is pulling from a query, it's dynamic.  This lable link is preserved when the project is published to PMF.  Every time the layout view in the published document is refreshed, the CurDate value is updated.